# Groovy regex PatternSyntaxException when parsing GString-style variables

Tags: regex, groovy, gstring

Groovy here. I'm being given a `String` with GString-*style* variables in it like:

```
String target = 'How now brown ${animal}. The ${role} has oddly-shaped ${bodyPart}.'
```

Keep in mind, this is *not* intended to be used as an actual GString!!! That is, I'm not going to have 3 string variables (`animal`, `role` and `bodyPart`, respectively) that Groovy will be resolving at runtime. *Instead*, I'm looking to do 2 distinct things to these "target" strings:

- I want to be able to find all instances of these variables refs (`"${*}"`) in the target string, and replace it with a `?`; and
- I also need to find all instances of these variables refs and obtain a list (allowing dupes) with their names (which in the above example, would be `[animal,role,bodyPart]`)

My best attempt thus far:

```
class TargetStringUtils {
    private static final String VARIABLE_PATTERN = "\${*}"

    // Example input: 'How now brown ${animal}. The ${role} has oddly-shaped ${bodyPart}.'
    // Example desired output: 'How now brown ?. The ? has oddly-shaped ?.'
    static String replaceVarsWithQuestionMarks(String target) {
        target.replaceAll(VARIABLE_PATTERN, '?')
    }

    // Example input: 'How now brown ${animal}. The ${role} has oddly-shaped ${bodyPart}.'
    // Example desired output: [animal,role,bodyPart]    } list of strings  
    static List<String> collectVariableRefs(String target) {
        target.findAll(VARIABLE_PATTERN)
    }
}
```

...produces `PatternSytaxException` anytime I go to run either method:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 0
${*}
^
```

Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Comment: Use `String VARIABLE_PATTERN = /\$\{([^{}]*)\}/`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew (+1), that solves the exception, but `collectVariableRefs(...)` now returns `[${animal}, ${role}, ${bodyPart}]` whereas I am looking for `[animal, role, bodyPart]`...any ideas?

Comment: You need to just grab the capture group #1 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have not escaped the pattern properly, and `findAll` will only collect all matches, while you need to *capture* a subpattern inside the `{}`.

Use

```
def target = 'How now brown ${animal}. The ${role} has oddly-shaped ${bodyPart}.'
println target.replaceAll(/\$\{([^{}]*)\}/, '?') // => How now brown ?. The ? has oddly-shaped ?.

def lst = new ArrayList<>();
def m = target =~ /\$\{([^{}]*)\}/
(0..<m.count).each { lst.add(m[it][1]) }
println lst   // => [animal, role, bodyPart]
```

See [this Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/QI4XUx)

Inside a `/\$\{([^{}]*)\}/` slashy string, you can use single backslashes to escape the special regex metacharacters, and the whole regex pattern looks cleaner.

- `\$` - will match a literal `$`
- `\{` - will match a literal `{`
- `([^{}]*)` - Group 1 *capturing* any characters other than `{` and `}`, 0 or more times
- `\}` - a literal `}`.

Comment: The snippet is a rough bit of code, but it shows the main direction.